# Firebase Go wants host "firebaseio.com"

Tags: go, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to firebase and I'm trying to setup a small test with a simple database in Go.
I struggle a lot with the database connection. Here is my code:

```
tx := context.Background()
conf := &firebase.Config{
    DatabaseURL: "https://mydb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",
}
// Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
opt := option.WithCredentialsFile("./fireBasePrivateKey.json")

// Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
app, err := firebase.NewApp(ctx, conf, opt)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("Error initializing app:", err)
}

client, err := app.Database(ctx)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("Error initializing database client:", err)
}
```

With that code (which comes from the official documentation), I've got an error on the Database client initialization:

> invalid database url: wants host: .firebaseio.com

I then tried with the requested url: mydb.firebaseio.com -> I've got another error telling me my db is not in that region and gives me the previous db address.

I also tried other things like mydb.europe-west1.firebaseio.com but here it says me the certificate is not valid for this url...

I'm a bit lost. I understand the problem has to do with the localization of the DB I choose when I created it, but I don't understand how to handle it with the go implementation.

Comment: The `<projectname>.firebaseio.com` format used to be the only format for Firebase Database URLs until early last year. Nowadays, databases in the US still use that format, but databases in other regions use the `<dbname><region>.firebasedatabase.app` format that you have. But as far as I can tell, the Go SDK has been updated to accept this. Can you open your `fireBasePrivateKey.json` file and check if it has the wrong database URL by any chance?

Comment: I have no Database url in this json, only type, project_id, private_key, client_email/id, auth_uri, token_uri, x509_cert url

Comment: Hey @JM445. Did you get anywhere with this? As I said in my answer below, most likely this is due to the version of the SDK you use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<projectname>.firebaseio.com` format used to be the only format for Firebase Database URLs until early last year. Nowadays, databases in the US still use that format, but databases in other regions use the `<dbname><region>.firebasedatabase.app` format that you have.

Support for the newer URL format was added in [PR #423](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go/pull/423) and released in [version 4.6 of the Go Admin SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go/releases/tag/v4.6.0), which was released in June. Upgrade to this version (or later), to ensure you don't get the error message anymore.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/migrate-go-v4
Can check this link on how to upgrade.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen thanks for the advice - here's another tip for migrating from v3 to v4 - the package name changed from firebase.google.com/go in v3 to firebase.google.com/go/v4. Easiest way to upgrade go.mod is append /v4 to the import pkg name, save changes then run 'go mod tidy'. In my case go pkg manager downloaded and applied v4.8.0. All fixed !